# Brain.js Artificial Neural Network predicting missing variables value

Tags: javascript, neural-network, brain.js

I am using this code for the training and then how would I alter the process so when I run the test data inside the neural network so that it shall give the value of the missing variable (z)?

```
const x1 = {
  x: 0.9,
  y: 0.2,
  z: 0.05
}

const x2 = {
  x: 0.01,
  y: 0.342,
  z: 0.2
}

const x3 = {
    x: 0.0 ,
    y: 0.1,
    z: 0.65
}

net.train([{
    input: x1,
    output: {
      x1: 1
    }
  }, {
    input: x2,
    output: {
      x2: 1
    }
  }, {
    input: x3,
    output: {
      x3: 1
    }
  }
]
);
const testdata = {
  x: 0.0,
  y: 0.0
}
```

Comment: Did you follow any tutorial? There is an example called “XOR training“ right on the homepage of brain.js. It shows how to predict z from x,y